# how to drop lines when streaming from a file using Haskell and the turtle library

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

Let's say I want to stream from one file to another file but I want to skip the first n lines of the input file. How do I do this without first collapsing the whole first file using 'fold' ?

```
import Turtle
main = output "/tmp/b.txt" (f (input "/tmp/a.txt"))
```

What should 'f' be here to accomplish this ?

ps: I don't have enough reputation to create the 'haskell-turtle' tag.

Comment: I'm not sure a `haskell-turtle` tag is really warranted, so I wouldn't worry about creating it.

Comment: Actually, the `turtle` documentation specifically requested this tag at [the very end](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.0.1/docs/Turtle-Tutorial.html#g:16), but I can remove that request if you think the `haskell` tag is appropriate enough

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez, I think it's probably better to wait for the download numbers to creep up just a bit first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the correct code:

```
import Data.IORef
import Turtle

drop :: Int -> Shell a -> Shell a
drop n s = Shell (\(FoldM step begin done) -> do
    ref <- newIORef 0
    let step' x a = do
            n' <- readIORef ref
            writeIORef ref (n' + 1)
            if n' < n then return x else step x a
    foldIO s (FoldM step' begin done) )
```

... except I'd probably call it something other than `drop` to avoid clashing with the Prelude.

It's almost identical to `Turtle.Prelude.limit` (See [source code](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Turtle-Library/blob/master/src/Turtle/Prelude.hs#L675) for comparison).  The only difference is that I've reversed the `then` and `else` clause of the `if` statement.

If that solves your problem then I'll add it to `Turtle.Prelude`.

Comment: Do you think its worth adding the `import Data.IORef` to the snippet? I know that Turtle is partly aimed at beginners so I thought it might be worthwhile.

Comment: Fixed.  I added necessary imports

Comment: That solves it. That's quite a "low level" solution, I wouldn't have come up with it for sure. Might be worth adding it to the library. Btw, in  similar way, is it possible to collapse every n lines into one line and pass the resulting lines to the output file in a streaming fashion ? thanks

Comment: The main reason it's low level is the need to get exception safety correct.  If not for that then I could replace `Shell` with a simpler abstraction like `ListT IO`.

Comment: For your second question, I'd just take the time to understand how `Shell` works.  There are some more general ways to do this but they would not be highly reusable.

Comment: I just want to cast a vote to include this into Prelude.Turtle! By the way, you need to add a "import Prelude hiding (drop)" at the top of the code. Otherwise it works.